# If one said shehecheyanu on a fruit, and later reminded himself that he had eaten it previously that seasons, Is his brachah a Brachah L'vatala?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shehecheyanu, bracha-levatala

If one said the bracha of *shehecheyanu* on a fruit, thinking that he had not eaten it that season yet, and afterward reminded himself that he had eaten it previously that seasons, is his brachah a *Brachah L'vatala*?

Do we say that since he had eaten it previously he had no obligation to say the shehecheyanu, so it would be a Brachah L'vatala,

or

Did the chachamim require the bracha of shehecheyanu to be said when one eats a fruit and has the enjoyment/ happiness of eating a new fruit, which he did have, (since in his mind he was indeed eating a new fruit), and thus his brachah would not be a Brachah L'vatalah?

Some ramifications:

1- Must he say ברוך שם ...

2- Must he do תשובה ?

3- If someone else who really had not eaten that fruit yet was יוצא with his brachah- Does he have to repeat the brachah? ( בדיעבד one can say the brachah as long as the simcha of the eating is still going on).

4 - הרי את מקודשת לי ע"מ שזה ברכה לבטלה would it be a valid קידושין?

If someone suffers from amnesia, and he has forgotten that he had already eaten this fruit, may we allow him to say *Shehecheyanu* on it?

Comment: @DoubleAA Are we supposed to assume that most readers are complete עמי הארץ and do not have the capacity of understanding anything that is not explained ברחל בתך הקטנה?

Comment: See the [site policy on jargon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/site-policy-on-jargon). Many of your Hebrew terms would be suitable to be translated.

Comment: @ribbis we don't write posts just for most readers. the internet is a big place.